# different table for insert and select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

In order to improve insert performance and load on server, I've decided to divide a large table into 2. A big table which will only be used for "select" and a smaller table which will be used mainly for "insert" and sometimes also "select". Each time period (I thought about a day) I will merge the smaller table into the big one.

Regrading the big table: is there a way I can improve performance by telling the mysql server it's read-only? Considering it's only for select, can I assume it will handle SELECT in less than 1sec. when it will become ~1e9 rows?

Regarding the small table: any tuning I should do here? what is the best way to develop an automated merge process from the small to the big table (in php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this and similar strategies used for this purpose and it has always been counterproductive. You end up creating complexity with more overhead that you gain. For instance, you are guaranteeing that every record gets inserted at least twice.

Be sure to benchmark carefully and compare to confirm your hypothesis before going too far with this.

I've found it's highly effective to circumvent deletes on MyISAM tables. You could for instance switch to a new small table once a day and merge the old one into the big one once both are read-only; then drop the old one. Once deletes start showing up in a MyISAM table its efficiency drops significantly from having to find and reuse empty holes.

Konerak's suggestion about packed ISAM tables is a good complement to this point of view. One effect is that it gives you a table (and indexes) without holes.

Comment: What do you mean by "without holes"?

Comment: A `DELETE` operation on a MyISAM table doesn't phyically delete the row and move all subsequent rows (or something else), but just marks the row as deleted. That row now is a 'hole'. Next time you do an `INSERT`, MyISAM will try to re-use a hole for your new row. The search for a hole can be slow.

Comment: And as significantly, if the new record is a different size, the cluster boundaries can be moved.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you don't need this..

If your goal is to give more precedence to the `SELECT` query you can just do inserts with `INSERT DELAYED`.

Answer (score 3):

[Packed ISAM tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisampack.html) are perfect as MySQL readonly tables, but you'll still need the correct indexes for your heavy queries.

But do make sure this is the solution to your problem (and have considered other options, including indexes and partitioning)

Comment: Of-course I'm using indexes. Actually the SELECT works fine, the large bulk inserts are the very slow queries which put load on the server. I don't fully understand the point of partitioning. Isn't it very similar to indexes? Can you give an example for partitioning?

Comment: Take a look at [RANGE PARTITIONING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html). If your queries use the ranges as defined, this indeed has the same effect as an index, with added efficiency if you put the partitions on seperate hard disks

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need to maintain different tables for SELECT and INSERT, mainly so if the number of INSERTs isn't very large or frequent. If the table has the right indexes, the SELECT will be efficient. However please note too many indexes might kill the INSERTs.

By maintaining different tables, I do not think it's any benefit to the server load because there will anyways be 2 INSERTs running per record.

You may also like to look into INSERT DELAYED if you think the SELECTs have a higher priority but I'd suggest you read them enough before using them.

I'll also suggest that you use InnoDB because it uses row-level locking.

You can also try partitioning; I think in your case it might be horizontal partitioning. Though I admit I myself have no experience using it.

However, if splitting tables is what you think might work best, I'll suggest you to explore other alternatives. Like instead of migrating data from the INSERT table to the SELECT table, you might use the same table for INSERT and SELECT, but maintain multiple tables, for example one for each month or any other criteria that fits you. You may then build logic to decide which table to run your query on. You may also eventually merge the old tables to create one large and DROP the old ones.